# Вживання прикметників оранжевий та помаранчевий

Tags: вживання-слів, синоніми, прикметники

СУМ-11 містит обидва прикметники

> [Оранжевий](http://sum.in.ua/s/oranzhevyj) а, е. Те саме, що жовтогарячий.
>
> [Помаранчевий](http://sum.in.ua/s/pomaranchevyj)1. Прикм. до помаранча і помаранч. 2. Який має колір
>   шкірки помаранчі; оранжево-червоний.

Мене часто виправляють, що в українській мові немає кольору ***"оранжевий"***, а лише ***"помаранчевий"***.

Проте в [словнику синонімів](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9) ці прикметники подаються, як синоніми.

Чи можна вживати обидва слова, як взаємозамінні? Чи варто розмежовувати вживання цих прикметників?

Comment: Питанье-родич: [_Помаранчі_ чи _апельсини_?](/q/3035/585)

Comment: Вивчаєш Світ? — поповнюєш і мову...:)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Оранжевий* точно не є неправильним. Це слово не лише є в усіх словниках, а й щонайменше з кінця XIX ст. вживається в українській літературі, наприклад:

- > Ордери не менше, якъ и на мундурі, сияли золотомъ и різнобарвними стрічками въ куті простоі майорськоі гостинні, котору небога звала світлицею, однакъ зъ ними змагались ярко-оранжеві чорнобривці, понсовий королівъ-цвітъ и пишні пахучі звоздики (російськомовна повість П. Куліша «Майоръ» в перекладі на українську Л. Лонгина, у часописі «Правда (письмо наукове и литературне)» за 1867 рік, Львів).
- > Зірниця вийшла з палати, махнула хусточкою і до самих копитів Громовикового коня розіслався довгий міст з хмарок, застелений та обвішаний рожевими та оранжевими килимами та хустками (Іван Нечуй-Левицький, «Скривджені й нескривджені», 1886).
- > Довгаль так почервонів, що борода його стала страшенно жовта, а вуха оранжеві (Володимир Винниченко, «Таємна пригода», 1910).

Мені важко сказати, чи абсолютно синонімічні *оранжевий* і *помаранчевий*. Я завжди вважав їх повними синонімами, але за наведеним Вами ж тлумаченням із СУМ-11 — «помаранчевий = <…> оранжево-червоний <…>» — начебто випливає, що помаранчевий має бути ближчим до червоного, ніж оранжевий (який у свою чергу, відповідно, має бути ближчим до жовтого)? Чи це справді так, чи це просто неточність у СУМ-11, мені важко сказати.

А є ще слово [жовтогарячий](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=27254&page=914) (а також забуте [жовтожар](http://hrinchenko.com/slovar/znachenie-slova/15318-zhovtozhar.html)). У статті [«Оранжевий — помаранчевий»](https://ua-etymology.livejournal.com/82295.html) maksymus наводить свій погляд на історію цих слів і відтінки їх значень, а також є деякі цікаві коментарі. Щоправда, мені важко сказати, чи повністю правильна там інформація (зокрема, мене дивує те, що згідно з тією статтєю, на відміну від СУМ-11, оранжевий, навпаки, темніший за помаранчевий).

Answer (score 2):

[Вікіпедія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%86%D1%8C):

> У народі «помаранчем» («помаранчою») часто називають звичайний, солодкий апельсин (Cītrus sinēnsis)[3], проте насправді ці рослини належать до різних, хоча й споріднених видів. На честь померанця жовтогарячий колір також називають «помаранчевим» — останнім часом це слово набуло значного поширення в україномовних джерелах. У польській мові щодо обох видів цитрусових вживається назва pomarańcza: померанець називається pomarańcza gorzka («гіркий помаранч»), апельсин — pomarańcza chińska («китайський помаранч»).
>
> Назви «померанець», «помаранч», «помаранча» походять від італ. pomarancia (утвореного від pomo — «яблуко» + arancia — «апельсин»): перша через посередництво рос. померанец і нім. Роmеrаnzе, інші — через пол. pomarańcza.

Отже,  "помаранчевий" вживається в українській мові на позначення [**жовтогарячого**](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%86%D1%8C), [оранжево-червоного](http://sum.in.ua/s/pomaranchevyj)

[Оранжевий](http://litopys.org.ua/djvu/etymolog_slovnyk.htm) в ЕСУМ т. 4, с.207 "від фр. orange (апельсин; **жовтогарячий**), лат. arancia (ст. melarancia, букв. апельсинове яблуко).

Отже, ці 2 слова вживаються в українській мові вживають на позначення жовтогарячого кольору, що і підтверджує [cловник синонімів](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9), наведений Вами.

Answer (score 2):

## Коротко

**Вживати можна оба як взаємозамінні, але не завжди**.

Бо *помаранчевий* можна тлумачити також як *ора̀нжовочерво́ний*.

## Довго

### Головне джерело

[Англійсько-український словник назв кольорів і кольорознавства](//diasporiana.org.ua/slovniki-dovidniki/vovk-a-anglijsko-ukrayinskyj-slovnyk-nazv-koloriv-i-koloroznavstva/) ([Анатоль Вовк](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA_%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%B9_%D0%86%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87), редактор Богдан Струмінський), 1986 рік.

### Витяги

> Для англійського orange вибрано за відповідник слово — **оранжовий**, як назву недвозначну та найпрактичнішу. Народна назва **жовтогарячий** колір, хоч і вжита в деяких термінологічних словниках (А-9, А-26), дуже невигідна для творення складених назв кольорів. Такі переклади, як «жовтогарячожовтий» для англійського orange yellow чи «жовтожовтогарячий» для англійського yellow orange, неясні та незграбні. Прикметник **помаранчевий**, який у значенні кольору вживається головно на західноукраїнських землях, має теж неусталене значення. *Словник української мови* (А-5) описує його як **оранжово-червоний**, а не **оранжовий**. Назва **оранжовий**, загальновідома в Україні, засвідчена також в не-підсовєтських джерелах (нап. А-22). Окрім англійської, також німецька, французька та еспанська мови утворили назву цього кольору від цього самого слова.

> **orange** n. a. ора́нжовий (к. шкірки з помаранчі), помара́нчовий, жовтогаря́чий, о: к. посередній між жовтим і червоним [1, 2]; червона̀вожо́втий [3]; жовтий з червонуватим відтінком [С, для «жовтогарячий»], ора̀нжовочерво́ний [С, для «пома́ранчовий»].

#### Домовленості

« » — слова в таких лапках є дослівним перекладом англійської назви, невживаним, одначе, у мововжитку

##### Значення кодів джерел у реєстрі словника

[1] Merriam-Webster Collegiate Dictionary (Підрозділ В. ч. 17)
[2] American Heritage Dictionary (Підрозділ В. ч. 1)
[3] Oxford Illustrated Dictionary (Підрозділ В. ч. 13)
[С] **Словник української мови**, 11 томів (Підрозділ А. ч. 5)

##### Джерела і література до теми

(А-5) Білодід, І. К., гол. ред. **Словник української мови**, в 11-ти томах. АН УРСР, Київ, в-во «Наукова думка», 1970-1980.
(А-9) Вовчанецький, В. і Лепченко, Я. **Словник ботанічної термінології** (Проєкт). ВУАН, Харків і Київ, в-во УРЕ, 1932.
(А-22) Орел А. **Словник чужомовних слів**, у 3-х томах, Нью-Йорк, вид. автора, 1963-1966.
(А-26) Полонський, Х. **Словник природничої термінології** (рос.-укр.) (Проєкт). УАН, Київ, Держ. В-во України 1928.